# What is the difference between differentiability?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

What is the difference between differentiability at a point in R^2->R^2 and C^2->C^2?

Comment: Differentiability around a point in $\mathbb{R}^2$ means what it means in any space- there is a linear approximation of the function around the point. In $\mathbb{C}$ this definition still holds true but thanks to the additional structure in $\mathbb{C}$ we see that this can only happen when the Cauchy Riemann equations are met. Thus,  differentiability in $\mathbb{C}$ is a special case of differentiability in $\mathbb{R}$ with extra restrictions (CR eqns) owing to the additional structure on $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: In $\mathbb{R}^2$ if a function satisfied the cauchy riemann eqns we would call them holomorphic.

Answer (score 1):

For one, $\mathbb{C}^2$ is not isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$. It's like asking about the difference between differentiability for $f:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$ versus $g:\mathbb{R}^4\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^4$.

If you're asking about the case for a function $f:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$, if it is complex-differentiable, then the same function over $\mathbb{R}^2$ will be real-differentiable.
The converse doesn't always hold, e.g. if we have $f_C(z)=\frac{z+\bar{z}}{2}$, then this is equivalent to $f_R(x,y)=x$. $f_R$ is differentiable everywhere, but $f_C$ is not complex-differentiable anwhere.